# Lubuntu autostart command problem

Tags: lubuntu

I tried adding:

`xinput set-prop DEVICEID "Device Enabled" 0`

where `DEVICEID` is a number taken after running the command `xinput`

to `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart` in lubuntu 16.04.

but what actually worked was:

`xinput --disable DEVICEID`

The question is, what is causing the first command I tried to fail, how would I get commands like that to work?

Note: what this command does after placing it in the autostart file, is that it disables the device on OS startup.

References:

[Configuring Lubuntu to run a script when LXDE starts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391102/configuring-lubuntu-to-run-a-script-when-lxde-starts)

[Permanently Disable Touchpad - Lubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819789/permanently-disable-touchpad-lubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `--set-prop`?

Comment: I think I tried that already.